# Ruby - protect a variable while iterating through a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, scope

I'm trying to perform an action with a nested array through a loop.  The loop executes once but then I get a nomethod error because the variable is not reset.

```
array = [[9, 2, 0, 0], [4, 1, 2, 2], [7, 1, 5, 5], [6, 1, 3, 1]]
comments = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]] 

def shift_comments(array)
  array.each {|x| x.shift} 
end

def map_distance_coordinants(array)
  array2 = array.map {|x,y| [Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)]}
  array2
end

def input_is_comment_format(array, comments)

  distance_coordinants = shift_comments(comments)

  mapped_coordinanats = map_distance_coordinants(distance_coordinants)

  print mapped_coordinanats
  print comments
end

i = 0
while i < array.length
  input_is_comment_format(array[i], comments)
  i += 1
end
```

Returns:

```
[[0.0], [1.4142135623730951], [2.8284271247461903]][[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
temp4.rb:9:in `block in map_distance_coordinants': undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How do I protect 'comments' so that I can use it for each iteration of the loop?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping what your desire is from all this code. If you don't get good answers, you might consider paring this down to a more general case, and specifying what you want for the output.

Comment: BTW, I think the word you may be looking for is [coordinate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coordinate).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup):

```
input_is_comment_format(array[i], comments.dup)
```

so you have a copy of the array to work with and your original array won't be modified.